# NSButton Multiple clicks

Tags: xcode, macos, button, click, ibaction

I have an IBAction of when the button is clicked to change my view.  How can I handle multiple clicks for example if I click the button a second time to cause another action?

Or do I need to delete the button after it has been clicked and then create a new one in its place? If so how do I handle the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `clickCount` of the mouseDown event:

```
if ([event clickCount] > 1)
{
    // ... do double-click action
}
else
{
    // ... do single-click action
}
```

Comment: Sorry Im a little new to xcode, how do you set a button to be an event?

Comment: You can make a sub-class of NSButton, make sure that your button is of that subclass and override the -mouseDown: event in your subclass.

Comment: if you have both a single click and double click action this will always fire the single click event before the double click event which isn't ideal (doesn't behave the same as like `doubleAction` on `NSTableView`)

Comment: Correct. That appears to be what the asker wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `NSClickGestureRecognizer` to the desired view from the storyboard Library as seen below

[image: Click getsure in library]

You can simply drag an IBAction from this object to the View controller

---

The Attributes inspector will provide you with many useful options like Number of clicks that should match and button masks

[image]